# Order of imports and paths in sys.path in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-3.4

I have a question regarding the order of imports and paths placed by default in `sys.path` by Python 2 and Python 3. I compared the default paths in my `sys.path` in both Python 2.7 and 3.4 with `PYTHONPATH` set to empty. I'm on Ubuntu 14.10.

I also have numpy installed both system-wide through apt-get in /usr/lib (version 1.8.2) and locally in `/home/user/.local/lib` (version 1.9.2) for both Python 2 and Python 3.

I get the following results:

**Python 2.7**

```
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))

/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7

>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version 
<module 'numpy.version' from  /home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/version.pyc'>
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.9.2'
```

**Python 3.4**

```
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3.4
/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages

>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version 
<module 'numpy.version' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/version.py'>
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.8.2'
```

Could you help me understand why in Python 3 `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` is higher than `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages` which results in my older system installation of numpy being imported by default, while it's the other way around in Python 2?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is an ubuntu thing, not a Python thing.  Check the global site customize (in `/etc/python2.7` and `/etc/python3.4`) as well as the `site.py` files in `/usr/lib/python2.7` and `/usr/lib/python3.4`.

Comment: There indeed are differences between the site.py files in /usr/lib/pythonX.X (no differences in /etc/pythonX.X). However, I cannot see anything obvious that would explain the difference I describe. I wasn't really aware of the existence of those files, though, and it's useful to know about them.

Comment: @AndrzejPronobis, I faced the same issue, how I can fix it, please?